# C# WPF Custom Titlebar & Animations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am making a custom titlebar for my application due to not being able to extend content into titlebar. I was able to recreate the button style, I could not figure out how to restore the original window animations, original captions/snap layout when you hover on Windows 11. I was able to use animations when I had `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"` and `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`, however I would like to have the window remain resizable. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Examples of things I want to keep/accomplish.
Snap Layout + Hover Tips[image: Win11 Snap Layout]

I have tried `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"` and `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`, this got animations back however, I want the window to be resizable. The MahApps.Metro Demo has exactly what I want, however I do not want to install it. The animations missing are minimizing, maximizing, and closing.

Update: Animations are working. I need to figure out the ControlzEx Demo and MahApps.Metro Demo magic as to how to restore the windows 11 snap layout when hovering over maximize button. I included example picture.

Comment: I think we need a little more detail here. Could you show us the XAML for the main window (at least the attributes) - how you want it to look - and then clarify exactly what kind of animations are missing? For instance I'm trying to understand if you're using `WindowStyle="None"` or something else.

Comment: @EmperorEto I am attempting to make it look like a standard titlebar. The missing animations are the minimize, maximize/restore, and close. The closest thing I can think of is MahApps.Metro's titlebar, the demo has everything I'd like, but I'd rather not install it.